# Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)

Tags: error-handling, bytecode, topic-modeling

I run this code:

```
from bertopic import BERTopic

bertopic_mod = BERTopic.load("bertopic_models/bertopic_complete")
```

I get one of the following errors (a different one each time):

```
IndexError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode) pop from empty list
```

or

```
AssertionError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode) key already in dictionary: 46
```

or

```
KeyError: 'Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)\n158'
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is "bertopic_models/bertopic_complete" a valid BERTopic file or file path?